# Why do we need to inherit from nn.Module in PyTorch?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, super

I am going through Udacity's [Intro To Deep Learning with Pytorch course](https://www.udacity.com/course/deep-learning-pytorch--ud188) In the Neural Network part the instructor says that "in the init method, we need to call super, we need to do that because then PyTorch will know to register all the different layers and operation, if you don't do this part it wont be able to track the things that you are adding to your network and it wont work". Could you kindly elaborate and explain what exactly is the role of super keyword here and what does nn.Module inherits which helps in "keeping track" of changes.

Further the Jupyter notebooks says the following about use of super,

```py
class Network(nn.Module):
```

> Here we're inheriting from `nn.Module`. Combined with
> `super().__init__()` this creates a class that tracks the architecture
> and provides a lot of useful methods and attributes. It is mandatory
> to inherit from `nn.Module` when you're creating a class for your
> network. The name of the class itself can be anything.

Comment: please refer to the official docs https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html

Comment: you can read this: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super-with-init-methods`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`class Network(nn.Module)` means that you defined a `Network` class that inherits all the methods and properties from `nn.Module` (`Network` is child class and `nn.Module` is parent class)

By using `super().__init__()` , Network's `__init__` will be same as its parent `__init__`.

```
class Network(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Network, self).__init__()
```

For example when you make a model:
`model = Network()` 
by calling this model, actually `nn.Module` will handle this call and track changes.

visit [this link](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/be757957bace28100e571ec7914765020be4a069/torch/nn/modules/module.py#L69) if you want to see `nn.Module` source codes.